# Change background color of iframe issue

Tags: html, iframe, background-color

I need to change background color to white of the displayed page if `<iframe></iframe>`. Is that possible? Now background of the original website is gray.

```
 <iframe allowtransparency="true" style="background-color: Snow;" src="http://zingaya.com/widget/9d043c064dc241068881f045f9d8c151" frameborder="0" height="184" width="100%">
    </iframe>
```

I want to change the background of loaded page

Answer (score 45, accepted):

An `<iframe>` background can be changed like this:

```html
<iframe allowtransparency="true" style="background: #FFFFFF;" 
    src="http://zingaya.com/widget/9d043c064dc241068881f045f9d8c151" 
    frameborder="0" height="184" width="100%">
</iframe>
```

I don't think it's possible to change the background of the page that you have *loaded* in the iframe.

Comment: I want to change the background of loaded page

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using javascript

- Change iframe background color
- Change background color of the loaded page (same domain)

Plain javascript

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
iframe.style.background = 'white';
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
```

jQuery

```
$('iframe').css('background', 'white');
$('iframe').contents().find('body').css('backgroundColor', 'white');
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is what you need. If you are loading iframe when loading the page, insert the test for iframe using the onload event. If iframe is inserted in realtime, then create a callback function on insertion and hook in whatever action you need to take :)

Comment: it would be nice, if could provide the code (I'm not good in Java Script)

Answer (score 2):

just building on what Chetabahana wrote, I found that adding a short delay to the JS function helped on a site I was working on. It meant that the function kicked in after the iframe loaded. You can play around with the delay.

```
var delayInMilliseconds = 500; // half a second

setTimeout(function() { 

   var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
   iframe.style.background = 'white';
   iframe.contentWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. With vanilla Javascript, you can use the function below for reference.

```
function updateIframeBackground(iframeId) {
    var x = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
    if (y.document) y = y.document;
    y.body.style.backgroundColor = "#2D2D2D";
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_contentdocument

Answer (score -1):

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
iframe.style.background = 'white';
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';function updateIframeBackground(iframeId) {
    var x = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
    if (y.document) y = y.document;
    y.body.style.backgroundColor = "#2D2D2D";<iframe allowtransparency="true" style="background: #FFFFFF;" 
    src="http://zingaya.com/widget/9d043c064dc241068881f045f9d8c151" 
    frameborder="0" height="184" width="100%">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Don't try this at loaded page

Answer (score -3):

Put the Iframe between aside tags

`<aside style="background-color:#FFF"> 
your IFRAME 
</aside>`

Comment: Might want to explain how putting an iframe in an aside will change its background color