# how to have iframe background color as same as its containing div

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, html, frame

I'm having a aspx page containing frame inside a Blue form div(will have Blue back ground in it). The page loaded inside the frame is white in colour when the page loaded completely the content in the frame is in white colour and it' container colour is blue. i want to make the content of frame's background to be as same as the blue form div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change background color of iframe issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830852/change-background-color-of-iframe-issue)

Answer (score 2):

The answer you're looking for is here. If you're trying to change the background color of the div loaded in the iframe, it won't be possible.

[Change background color of iframe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830852/change-background-color-of-iframe-issue)